# java return in the if statement

Tags: java

How to use the `return` to retrieve a value out of an `if` statement? I don't want to return immediately, just like that:

```
if(){
return "something";
}
```

This isn't working for me, because if the `return` is successful the method returns, but I need to return it and when the return is complete to continue the actions in the method.

Comment: You should only ever have one exit point for a function. IE, I would not recommend putting a return in a if statement.

Comment: This question should get a prize for having so many instant duplicate answers :)

Comment: @user Not only is that highly debatable, it has nothing to do with this; he doesn't want to return

Comment: Hah , just forgot to tell you it is in try :)

Comment: @user489041 there's nothing wrong with multiple return statements. Having only one exit point is an out-dated pattern.

Comment: @Steve Kuo - quote: "I don't want to return immediately".

Comment: Why not finish all the job before return? You can save the value in a local variable and return it at last. ALSO, if you want to do additional jobs like stream.close(), or other finalizations, you can return as you wish and surround your code with `try-finally` block, put the finalizations in `finally` part. --- NOTE: `catch` part is not necessary, as no exception will be thrown. `finally` part will be executed after return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "return" values from a method without actually `return`ing from the message, then you have to define setter methods on the calling class and call them, like this:

```
public class Caller {

     private boolean someState;

     // ...

     public void doSomething() {
         // the method call
         Worker w = new Worker(this);
         int result = w.workForMe();
     }

     public void setState(boolean state) {
         this.someState = state;
     }

}
```

And the `Worker`

```
public class Worker {

    private Caller caller;

    public Worker(Caller caller) {
        this.caller = caller;
    }

    public int workForMe() {
        // now the conditions:
        if(clearBlueSky) {
            // this emulates a "return"
            caller.setState(true);
        }
        // this returns from the method
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: +0: This has to be by far the most complex solution. ;)

Comment: @downvoter - As far as I understood the question: he/she wanted to *send* intermediate results to the caller without actually leaving the method. Which does not work with `return` (there's no way back).

Answer (score 10):

Try something like:

```
String result = null;

if(/*your test*/) {

    result = "something";

}

return result;
```

Comment: forgot to ell that the if is in try

Answer (score 4):

This should be the easiest way in your case

```
return yourCondition ? "ifTrue" : "ifFalse";
```

Answer (score 2):

Store your string in a variable.

```
String s = null;
if( somecondition ) {
    s = "something";
}
// do other stuff
return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` is for methods. You probably want something like this:

```
int foo;

if (someCondition) {
    foo = 1;
} else {
    foo = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a finally block or save the return value in a variable that you return at the end of your code.

Comment: @user639285, yes in a try statement, finally is designed for your specific case.  Use a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
String result = "unknown";
if(condition){
    result = "something";
}
// do something.
return result;
```